# why JSON.parse didn't work but type-casting to <any> did

Tags: javascript, typescript

I thought that `Objects` in Javascript and `JSON` are interchangeable. It this correct?

In my code, I am sending an object which looks like follows (received in HTTP body)

```
UserProfileAPI{external-profile: User{firstname: 'first', lastname: 'last', email: 'email', password: ''}}`
```

I tried to store the above in a variable `profile:UserProfileAPI;` using `JSON.parse` but I got the error `zone.js:192 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`. But when I use `<any>` the casting worked

```
this.profile = JSON.parse(response['additional-info']);//DOESNT WORK
```

but

```
this.profile = <any>response['additional-info'] as UserProfileAPI; //WORKS
```

Why `JSON.parse` didn't work?

Comment: That's not just JavaScript. Are you using TypeScript for Flow?

Comment: That's not valid javascript as far as I'm concerned

Comment: Sorry, yes. Its typescript

Comment: `<any>` is not JavaScript but TypeScript and it is not casting but an assertion. A TypeScript assertion is just a way to tell the compiler "don't bother to do type checking, I know what I'm doing". The assertion does't change the code in any way, it just suppresses a compiler error.

Comment: What is the contents of `response['additional-info']` ? Is it a JSON string, or a object?

Comment: *"I thought that Objects in Javascript and JSON are interchangeable. It this correct?"* -- it is completely wrong. [JSON](http://json.org) is not code, it is a text representation of some data structure.

Comment: I suspect that `response['additional-info']` is not JSON. Maybe you meant `JSON.parse(response)['additional-info']` ?